# Reg-ex catch the inverse of rule

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to get the tags in text

```
(<[^ ][^><]*>)
```

how can I make it to get everything except the tags ...

clarification  :
from [here](http://www.regexpal.com/) put the rule and this as the body

```
<asd> ba <asd><a>ddd</a>
```

I want to get everything other-than the `highlighted` text

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: there's no language in specific, the generic standers rules,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your regular expression to *match*, you can *split*.

```
x.split(/<[^ ][^><]*>/)
```

`split` returns everything that doesn't match as an array.

Comment: there's alot of walk around to solve the problem, i just want to increase my knowledge, thanks sir,

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

```
>([^<]*)<
```

do the trick? The group contains the strings you are looking for.

Comment: yes it dose, i just want to check if there is another way, specially how to make NOT in reg-ex

Comment: Some regex engines support look-around patterns, which I believe you could use the create something like a NOT. Have a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Also regex conditionals may be helpful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html